# PHP htmlentities quotes issue

Tags: php, quotes, html-entities

I have the joy of using recoding existing database data that has been entered directly into the SQL database without having htmlentities used. It is also a french website.

I am now trying to output this to the browser and all of the french characters are appearing fine through using htmlentities(), however the unecoded ’ and ‘ are giving me problems.

An example of the text I am trying to display is:

```
The ‘Maison de Maître’ is very...
```

And the code to display it

```
$p_title = htmlentities(stripslashes($pr['title']), ENT_QUOTES);
```

This does not work - I have also tried using UTF-8 as the charset which stops the title showing at all.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: "I have the joy of using recoding existing database data that has been entered directly into the SQL database without having htmlentities used." - you sound disgusted with that, but in fact it's how it should be: the database should not contain HTML.

Comment: What is the encoding used for the database? What encoding do you use when retrieving data from the database?

Comment: Haha how did you guess? It does make sense that it should be unecoded in the database, however on this occasion it's a little frustrating

Comment: You have to make sure that the character set used in all stages of the pipeline matches. Don't have an iso-8859 DB connection but set the output page to UTF-8 or whatever.  And as Lekensteyn says, storing encoded text in the database is the wrong way to go - always store raw data, and convert as needed for whatever purpose you're using the text for.

Comment: In what sense does it "not work" for you?  That is, what have you tried, what happened when you tried it, and how did it differ from what you expected?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this. It works for this specific problem, but I don't know if it does all that you need.

`$p_title = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($pr['title']), ENT_QUOTES);`